# BackgroundUploader and oauth WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to upload files to a service that uses oauth.
using httpclient I'm able to do it. but for larger files I want to use the backgrounduploader.

I'm setting the authorization header as i do  with the httpclient but it fails

```
   BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
        var headerParams = OAuthUtility.BuildBasicParameters(
            Domain.Super.Current.ConsumerKey
            , Domain.Super.Current.ConsumerSecret
            , uri.OriginalString, HttpMethod.Post, Domain.Super.Current.Token);



        var header = headerParams.Select(p => p.Key + "=" + p.Value.Wrap("\"")).ToString(",");
        uploader.Method = "POST";
        uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Oauth " + header);
```

Any ideias on what's wrong?

Comment: How it fails? Exception?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem!

it's not uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Oauth " + header);

but

uploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + header);

See the diference Oauth -> OAuth